# Checking if the page exists and making sure it doesn't cache

Tags: javascript, caching, xmlhttprequest

I have the code to check if a webpage exists that is working perfectly fine, but I need to check if it exists many times a second. Would this code cache, or would it check every time?

```
var url = "urlhere"+"?noCachePlease="+(Math.random()*1000000);
var aa = setInterval(function() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (request.readyState === 4){
            if (request.status === 404) {  
                //Site DNE
            }  
        else { clearInterval(aa); }
        }
    };
    request.send();
}, 50);
//Afterwards
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783442/how-to-tell-if-an-xmlhttprequest-hit-the-browser-cache

Comment: I can't test this manually at the moment which is the only reason I asked. How would I make it not cache if it does?

Comment: worst case, just slap a random query parameter onto the url, fooling the browser into thinking it's a new url each time. e.g. `'sitehere?randomtime='+ Date.now()`

Comment: Would what I just added to it work?